# How to remove a view from layout in RCP

Tags: eclipse, view, rcp

I have an application where I have different perspective.In one perspective I want to remove certain views which has been added to the layout.
Below is my snippet:

This is the snippet which I call when I want to reset perspective

```
public void createInitialLayout(IPageLayout layout) {
        layout.setEditorAreaVisible(false);
        layout.setFixed(false);

        //I am dividing the whole layout into 4 parts.One is top left,top right,bottom left,bottom right.

        IFolderLayout topLeft = layout.createFolder(TOP_LEFT_ID, IPageLayout.LEFT, 0.25f, IPageLayout.ID_EDITOR_AREA);
        topLeft.addView(SpaceView.ID);
        topLeft.addView(RepositoryView.ID);

        IFolderLayout topRight = layout.createFolder(TOP_RIGHT_ID, IPageLayout.TOP, 0.25f, IPageLayout.ID_EDITOR_AREA);
        topRight.addView(ModuleView.ID);
        topRight.addView(ProjectChangeLogView.ID);
        topRight.addView(SearchViewPart.ID);

        IFolderLayout bottomLeft = layout.createFolder(BOTTOM_LEFT_ID, IPageLayout.BOTTOM, 0.70f, TOP_LEFT_ID);
        bottomLeft.addView(QueueView.ID);

        IFolderLayout bottomRight = layout.createFolder(BOTTOM_RIGHT_ID, IPageLayout.BOTTOM, 0.55f, TOP_RIGHT_ID);
        bottomRight.addView(Objects.ID);

    }
```

Now after the perspective got reset ,I want to remove certain views (e.g Object view) from the layout.Here I dont get any option for bottomRight.delelte/removeView etc.So how can I achieve the same?

Comment: Each perspective has its own layout. Are you using a different perspective factory for each perspective?

Comment: Yes I have different perspective factory for each perspective.So suppose lets say in one perspective I have fixed one layout.Now staying in the same layout can I re arrange the position of the views on click of a button .Like taking one view from bottom right to top right.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The perspective factory is only used when the perspective is first used and when it is reset. It can't be used to change the layout of an open perspective.

I don't know of a simple way to move the position of views. You probably need to modify the e4 application model by moving the `MPart` to a new `MPartStack` in a similar way to the drag and drop code (`org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.dndaddon.DnDManager`)

Comment: Currently I am using eclipse-indigo-3.7.2.Sorry for missing this part.so how can I achieve the same in this version?

Comment: Sorry but I have no idea what you would do in such an old version.